# Unit testing using sinon stub promise and axios

Tags: node.js, axios, proxyquire

I am trying to test my node js api using sinon. I have a function **appRequest()**  that returns the appDetails; but I am not able to get the result. I am using proxyquire to get the result but its not working.

**appService.js**

```
function appRequest(apprequestData) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     console.log(apprequestData);
    axios.get(url + apprequestData.dataId).then(appResult => {
        console.log('appResult'+appResult);
        if ('' == appResult.data.result || appResult.data.result[0].dataId!= apprequestData.dataId) {
            reject({
                status: 404,
                message: "APP not Found"
            });
            return;
        }
        resolve({
            clientId: appResult.data.result[0].dataId
        });

    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        if (null == error.response || error.response.status == 404) {
            reject({ status: 404, message: "APP service down", referenceNumber: apprequestData.referenceNumber });
            return;
        }
        reject({ status: 404, message: "APP service down", referenceNumber: apprequestData.referenceNumber });
        return;
    });
});
```

}

**app.test.js**

describe("App request", function() {

```
describe('get app details', () =>{
 var appDetails, teststub;
 let req = {
  "dataId": "1234"
}

let response={ "dd":23}

//  teststub = sinon.stub(axios,'get').resolves(Promise.resolve(response));
teststub = sinon.stub();

it('should return app ', function() {

     appDetails = proxyquire('../app/service/appService', { 'axios': teststub.returns(response)}) 
      console.log(appDetails);
      var result=appDetails.appRequest(req);
      console.log("***"+JSON.stringify(result)); // this is coming as empty
      expect(result.statusCode).equal(200);
      });


});
```

});